# Compressing PDF to ZIP and save in table inside SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion, zip

I'm getting a Base64 file send by some application to my application and I need to Decode it in SQL, make that file to be a *.zip and then store as a zip in a proper column in table.

The decoding part is ready. Now, I'm stuck on the step in which I need to make that file to be a ZIP.

The question is: Is there any way or chance to make the compression only using SQL?

Comment: Converting it into a zip isn't a job for the RDBMS, no, that's something for the application layer.

Comment: Databases aren't normally the right/best place to store files or serve files from.  Host the files on a file server, and store the URLs in the database.